# Haskell recursive data type for appending

Tags: haskell, types

I am learning Haskell and have run into something I don't quite understand.  I have the following recursive data type:

```
data TList a = Tnil | Tcons (TList a) a
```

When I look at this I understand it as creating a data type called TList with a generic type a.  That has two constructors Tnil and Tcons.  Basically I am trying to add a function that appends two list so I wrote the following pattern matching function:

```
tappend :: TList a -> TList a -> TList a
tappend (Tcons t h) y = Tcons h (tappend t y)
```

I keep getting an error when trying to run it that says something along the lines of  " Couldn't match expected type ‘TList (TList a)’ with actual type ‘a’ " Also if someone could possible break down the data type I created that would be great.  The recursive part is what I just haven't been able to wrap my head around it.

Comment: Shouldn't `Tcons` have parameters `a (TList a)`?

Comment: Whys that?  I guess I should of said that I am creating a reversed list.

Comment: `tappend` should be something like `TList a -> a -> TList a`. You are trying to implement something closer to `++`.

Comment: Please do not vandalise questions -- even if you happen to have posted them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is sometime that is a bit *uncommon* in your definition:

```
data TList a = Tnil | Tcons (TList a) a
```

Here `Tcons` has as first parameter a `TList a`, followed by an `a`. Which thus means that you will probably first specify an `init` (the first part of the list), followed by a `last` (the last element). Usually a linked list is defined in the opposite way: with a `Tcons` that first has a `head` (an `a`) followed by a `tail`: a `TList a` that contains the rest of the list.

But let us for now use the above definition. Let us inspect the parameters:

```
tappend :: TList a -> TList a -> TList a
tappend (Tcons t h) y = Tcons h (tappend t y)
```

Here at the right we see that you construct a new `Tcons`, but as first parameter, you use `h`, which is an `a`, as second parameter you use `tappend t y` that will produce a list, so you called the constructor with flipped parameters. We can fix it with:

```
tappend :: TList a -> TList a -> TList a
tappend (Tcons t h) y = Tcons (tappend t y) h
```

But now we still will get an error, since we did not take into account what we should do in case we encounter a `Tnil`, in that case we can return the second list:

```
tappend :: TList a -> TList a -> TList a
tappend Tnil y = y
tappend (Tcons t h) y = Tcons (tappend t y) h
```

Now the function will compile, and work. But the result is a bit strange. In case we use for example:

```
tappend [1, 4, 2, 5] [1, 3, 0, 2]
```

(of course we can not use list syntax), we will have as output:

```
tappend [1, 3, 0, 2, 1, 4, 2, 5]
```

So in fact we will append these but in a flipped way. It is not very clear to me how you want the semantics of the `tappend` function.